# Ubuntu LTS Desktop - How can I configure complete synchronisation between two desktop computers. Applications, Settings, Files and folders?

Tags: settings, sync, mirrors, realtime, duplicate-files

I need to set a realtime synchronisation between 2 or 3 Ubuntu LTS Desktops.
All applications, all files and folders, all setting, all changes in a real time. And if somebody, makes changes of one of these computers, this to be sended and synchronized to the others.. and back.

Is is possible, or not? Could you share some fresh ideas?

Comment: Are these computers will be used by different people? If so, what will be your choice if person A and person B changes the same file in different ways? Which one should be the one sent to the other/s?

Comment: @Emre Talha,
Thank you very much for your attention!
The computers will be used only from one person.

Comment: ...Also some of the computers will have a few user accounts. But it is necessary only one to be synchronized with the other computers with the same user accounts. I hope you understand me well.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, one would use `rsync` to synchronize two computers.

However, I think what you're asking for may be much more complicated. You say *"all applications"*, but then *"only one to be synchronized with the other computers with the same user accounts"*. Most applications are installed for all users, while the data will be per-user, and configuration may be *either*.

You would need to:

1. Either copy `/etc/passwd` from another computer and compare it to the local `/etc/passwd` for all accounts with uid >= 1000, to find which accounts to sync, or else just keep a list of accounts to sync
2. Get a list of all installed debian packages from the remote computer, compare it to the list on the local computer, and install them all on both (`dpkg --get-selections`)
3. Do the same for Snaps, Flatpaks, Node, etc (this could get very tedious very fast!)
4. `rsync` (in both directions) `/etc/PACKAGE` and `etc/default/PACKAGE` for every PACKAGE found in step 2
5. `rsync /home/USER` for every USER found in step 1
6. Put all of this into a cron job running regularly from one machine only.

And then you'll surely find there's something you (or I) have forgotten!
And don't even think of doing this without backups.